# how to update :APP_USER detail in a field, apex5.0

Tags: oracle-apex-5

Any idea how to add :APP_USER in an audit field?
Got a form when user input data in a order_comments field and click on apply changes then the audit field userid, datetime should be updated.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An age-old question.

The common method to capture the user for audit purposes is to use a before-row trigger on the tables.

For example, with these (common) audit fields:

- `CREATION_USER`
- `CREATION_DT`
- `LAST_UDPATE_USER`
- `LAST_UPDATE_DT`

You'd have a trigger on the table like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TABLE_RBIU_AUDIT
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MY_TABLE
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    :NEW.CREATION_USER := NVL(v('APP_USER'), USER);
    :NEW.CREATION_DT := SYSDATE;
  END IF;

  IF UPDATING THEN
    :NEW.LAST_UPDATE_USER := NVL(v('APP_USER'), USER);
    :NEW.LAST_UPDATE_DT := SYSDATE;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

If you don't want to use a trigger and are not using an API through which you do this, and for some weird reason want to do this within apex itself (hint: use the trigger or api), you can still opt to set the default value of the item to `&APP_USER.` (when using "Static Text")

Comment: Hi Tom, Ive created below but not working can  u check

Comment: CREATE TABLE ORDER_AUDIT
( id_order VARCHAR2(30), pt_user  VARCHAR2(30), pt_date  DATE, pt_code  VARCHAR2(30), pt_name  VARCHAR2(30));

Comment: CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER  TEST_TRG
BEFORE UPDATE on TEST_TBL  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
v_pt_code VARCHAR2(20);
v_pt_user VARCHAR2(30); 
v_pt_date  DATE;   
BEGIN   
  IF :NEW.PT_DATE is null then 
SELECT substr(b.CODE,3,10) INTO V_PT_CODE
FROM   order_tbl b, empl_tbl a
WHERE  a.ID = b.ID AND SUBSTR(a.emp_name,1,15) =:APP_USER;
select nvl(v('APP_USER'), USER) into V_PT_USER from dual;
:NEW.PT_CODE := V_PT_CODE; 
:NEW.PT_USER := V_PT_USER;
:NEW.PT_DATE := SYSDATE;
END IF; 
END;

Comment: @user7285351 You didn't specify "the error" so I'll make some assumptions about the code: you used `:APP_USER` in the trigger in your first select. You don't use bind variable syntax in your trigger code, that's what the `v('APP_USER')`  is for. Also, you don't need a `select ... from dual` to assign the value.

Comment: I've created a form when the date is entered and updated in then fields PT_CODE, PT_USER, PT_DATE should be updated.... 
For my first select it need to do a substring with the :APP_USER

SELECT substr(b.CODE,3,10) INTO V_PT_CODE
FROM   order_tbl b, empl_tbl a
WHERE  a.ID = b.ID AND SUBSTR(a.emp_name,1,15) =:APP_USER;

Comment: can u please review the trigger and amend it for me..  with the :APP_user i'm getting bind variable error while compiling.  and its not updating correctly when im hardcoding the :app_user